# PHP foreach array in array how to traverse?

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to traverse the following data set i got using a foreach but some reason i cant figure out whats wrong ?

Code:

```
foreach($data['service']['products'] as $settings){
        print_r($settings);
}
```

$data as print_r

```
Array
(
    [service] => Array
        (
            [products] => Array
                (
                    [name] => OW VoIP
                    [settings] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [name] => ComplexPort
                                    [value] => False
                                )

                            [1] => Array
                                (
                                    [name] => LosingCarrier
                                    [value] => 2
                                )
```

Data as var_dump

```
array (size=3)
  'service' => 
    array (size=1)
      'products' => 
        array (size=2)
          'name' => string 'VoIP' (length=7)
          'settings' => 
            array (size=21)
              0 => 
                array (size=2)
                  'name' => string 'ComplexPort' (length=11)
                  'value' => string 'False' (length=5)
              1 => 
                array (size=2)
                  'name' => string 'LosingCarrier' (length=13)
                  'value' => string '2' (length=1)
```

Comment: `foreach ($data['service']['products']['settings'] as $settings) {}`

Comment: Please show us the structure of your array and what you want to loop thrue!

Comment: see above its already there @Rizier123

Comment: @mahen3d but through what you want to loop?

Comment: what i want is to loop through products and then all settings for that products but i cant even get to the products

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for you to loop trough all products and their settings:

```
foreach($data['service'] as $products){
    foreach($products as $settings) {
        if (is_array($settings))
            print_r($settings);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach([arrayLvL1][arrayLvL2][arrayLvL3] as $key => $value){
     echo $value 
}
```

i think should do it.

Also someone in the comments said the same thing. I'm not sure how to link to their comment.

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
foreach($data['service']['products']['settings'] as $settings){
```

Answer (score -1):

I do not see the results you are getting. Are you punking us? Your result should not be possible.

```
$arr = array(
            'service' => array(
                            'products' => array(
                                                'name' => 'VoIP',
                                                'settings' => array(
                                                                    0 => array(
                                                                                'name' => 'ComplexPort',
                                                                                'value' => 'False'
                                                                                ),
                                                                    1 => array(
                                                                                'name' => 'LosingCarrier',
                                                                                'value' => 2
                                                                                )
                                                                    )
                                                )
                            )
            );

foreach($arr['service']['products']['settings'] as $settings) {
    echo '<pre>' . print_r($settings) . '</pre>';
}
```

WILL output

```
Array ( [name] => ComplexPort [value] => False )

1

Array ( [name] => LosingCarrier [value] => 2 )

1
```

Basically.. you are only handing it one array, products, or settings. It can't get the base array as it doesn't exist in the scope you provide the `foreach` event. And whoever down-voted this is pathetic and doesn't understand arrays either.